# Dynamic Laravel Scheduler Issue

Tags: laravel, dynamic, scheduler

I want to run the scheduler dynamically in laravel.i am selecting the value of the scheduler $frequency from database eg- twiceDaily(15,16).but when i am passing the variable value in the scheduler it is giving me the error(" Undefined property: Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent::$->twiceDaily(15, 16)").

Here is the code :-

```
 $schedule->call(function() use($task) {
                /*  Run your task here */
                Log::info($task->title.' '.\Carbon\Carbon::now());
            })->$frequency();
```

Where $frequency is the value i am fetching from the database

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier and better to use a cron expression.

```
$frequency = "0 15,16 * * *";

$schedule->call(function() use($task) {
                /*  Run your task here */
                Log::info($task->title.' '.\Carbon\Carbon::now());
            })->cron($frequency);
```

I recommend you use cron. All those scheduler methods are formatted into cron expressions anyway.

```
->twiceDaily(15, 16) returns ->cron("0 15,16 * * *")
```

You can see this in:
*\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ManagesFrequencies.php*

If you want to see the cron expression it is stored in the expression property.

```
echo $schedule->call(function() {})->dailyAt('13:00')->expression;
```

output:

```
0 13 * * *
```

But cron expressions are really easy so it might be better if you invest 15 minutes to understand them.

Comment: how can i convert scheduler value stored in database in cron expression

Comment: From where are you getting these values? Are these manually entered or generated somehow? Probably you just need to update your data to proper cron expressions. Use something like https://crontab.guru/ if you are not familiar with cron.

Comment: I have stored these values in the database as per the laravel scheduler list

Comment: Show us what you have stored.

Comment: >dailyAt('13:00');
->weeklyOn(1, '8:00');
->twiceDaily(1, 13);

I have stored this way in database

Comment: I've edited my answer on how you can get these cron expressions.

Comment: How can i call dynamic cron expression.as i am passing dynamic value in the function it is giving me error.
dynamic value :- 
echo $schedule->call(function () {
            })->$task_frequency->expression;

Error i am getting :-  Undefined property: Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent::$everyMinute()

Comment: This is the error i am getting :- 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent::$everyMinute()